# purrr return a list of different length for every element

Tags: r, dictionary, tidyverse, purrr

I have a strange issue with map. My goal is to return a list for every element. Conditional on the element I want a list of different length (or at least different logic applied to it). This seems to be very difficult and map is returning all kinds of values (see below):

```
map(1:2, ~ list(.x, .x + 1))
# returns list(list(1,2), list(2,3)

map(1:2, ~ ifelse(.x > 1,
                  list(.x, .x + 1),
                  list(.x, .x)))
# returns list(list(1), list(2))

map(1:2, ~ case_when(.x > 1 ~ list(.x, .x + 1),
                     TRUE ~ list(.x)))
# returns list(list(1,1), list(2,3)
```

I found two methods to solve this:

```
# Add a list around it and then remove the list
map(1:2, ~ ifelse(.x > 1,
                  list(list(.x, .x + 1)),
                  list(.x))) %>%
  map(., ~.[[1]])

# Use a two step map_if
map_if(1:2, ~.x > 1, 
       ~list(.x, .x + 1)) %>% 
  map_if(is.integer, ~list(.x))
```

Both feel a little weird to me.. What is the best practice in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `if/else` instead of `ifelse` or `case_when` as these require all arguments to be of same length (unless we `rep`licate`) i.e. the` test`is of`length` 1

```
library(purrr)
map(1:2, ~ if(.x > 1) list(.x, .x + 1) else list(.x, .x))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3
```

---

NOTE: Here each element from the vector is looped and thus we don't need an `ifelse`.  If we want to use it anyway, do the `ifelse` and wrap the output with the element looped in a `list`

```
map(1:2, ~ list(.x, ifelse(.x > 1,
                  .x + 1,
                  .x)))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(1:2, \(x) {test <- list(x, `+`(x > 1) + x); test[!duplicated(test)]})
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. While this works for this specific example, I accepted the other answer since it is more general.

Comment: No problem. You can accept any answer that you feel is best. I do disagree, however, that the other answers are more general. The answer I provide here is just as general as the others.